# I want to display monthwise data from the mysql DB

Tags: mysql

I have data only for november and december. For the other months I need to display as 'Zero'. How do i Achieve it?

Sample Data:

Month : December
Open: 2
Closed: 2
NoStatus: 5

Month : November
Open: 5
Closed: 7
NoStatus: 15

Expected Output:

Month :January (same format till October)
Open: 0
Closed:0
NoStatus:0

Month : December
Open: 2
Closed: 2
NoStatus: 5

Month : November
Open: 5
Closed: 7
NoStatus: 15

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Atleast add a table schema or sample data!

Comment: assuming you have 12 records in your database, just give default value 0 for the remaining 10. and when you are pulling all the records it will be easy.

Comment: hi Varun, Kindly see the sample

Comment: I have edited the acc to your sample

Comment: follow these steps: create 12 rows(records), then where ever you have data add those data into the row, for the row with no data insert 0 thats the best option you will be able to avoid null check and all that. If 0  is also par of data then you have to do null check in javascript,

Comment: Let me know if you are able to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with 1 column and 12 rows containing only months from january to dec

```
   CREATE TABLE months (name varhcar(15))
```

Then join this table with other one containing your data using OUTER JOIN
Assuming the name of you table to be **data**.

```
 SELECT IFNULL(x.open) AS Open,
  IFNULL(x.closed) AS Closed , 
  IFNULL(x.noStatus) AS NoStatus , 
  y.name AS Months 
  FROM months y 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN data x 
  ON x.month = y.name;
```

Used IFNULL function to display **0** instead of **NULL** . Apply it for every column you want **zero**.

```
IFNULL (column_name,0)
```

Comment: could you care elaborate a bit more how it will work,as he has to display 0 for the ones there are no records

Comment: @war_Hero : All my data are in a single table.

Comment: that's actually good, assuming your month is your not your primary key(as primary key cannot be null) just give default value 0 in its place. and it will be easy to show. where do you have to render this data like in html or java can you tell this

Comment: @war_Hero:in javascript

Comment: @varun don't you feel instead of all that complication a better and elegant approach will be to add 0 inside the column of that database  and render that

Comment: @warhero my approach is to produce the expected result in just one query. He has to just create a single table with all the months on it and then use sql join and in built functions. There is no need to add 0 for other months in the table , add the data whenever you feel like. Thats my point.

Comment: According to you @ warhero he will have to change the table schema first to add default zero then he will have to insert rows  for all other months . i think its better to create a small table with single column which can be useful not only for this problem but for any future problems too.